# xslt select distinct valued elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Consider the following xml:

```
<Images>
 <Extra1>a</Extra1>
 <Extra2>b</Extra2>
 <Img1>img1</Img1>
 <Img2>img2</Img2>
 <Img3>img2</Img3>
 <Img4>img1</Img4>
</Images>
```

I want a collection of distinct values for elements `Img1, Img2, Img3, Img4` so that the output node set has values `img1` and `img2`. I have used `xsl:key` earlier, but that requires all elements name to be same. How can I achieve that for different element names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kImageValue" match="Images/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Img')]"
           use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Images">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kImageValue', .)[1])]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Images/*">
    <Value>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Value>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<Images>
  <Value>img1</Value>
  <Value>img2</Value>
</Images>
```